# How do I parse json to run git commands from python?

Tags: python

My git repo is not getting checked out, I am new to python and I don't know why

My input arguments are in json and I need to read them and to checkout my git repo

Can someone help get what I am doing wrong?

```
class GitCheckout:
    def parse_json(self, text):
        self.json_dict = json.loads(text)
        self.extract_data()

    def extract_data(self):
        des = self.json_dict["dest"]
        src = self.json_dict["src"]
        ver = self.json_dict["ver"]
        self.generate_git_cmd(str(des), str(src), str(ver))

    def generate_git_cmd(self, des, src, ver):
        if os.path.isdir(des):
            stdout = self.run_cmd(['rm', '-rf', des])
            print(stdout)
        else:
            self.run_cmd(['mkdir', '-p', des])
        stdout = self.run_cmd(['git', 'clone', '--no-checkout', src, des])
        stdout = self.run_cmd(['--wd', des, 'git', 'checkout', '--detach', ver])

    def run_cmd(self, cmd):
        p = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True)
        p.stdout = p.stdout.decode("utf-8")
        return p.stdout

    def main(self):
        obj = GitCheckout()
        args = sys.argv
        obj.parse_json(self, args)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main
```

Comment: When you say "does not work" can you be more specific? Do you get an error message? Are the directories created but nothing is cloned?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry about that. All i see happening is an empty directory being created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` should be a call to a main function, thus it needs to be `main()`.

Also the whole if block is indented causing it to be part of the class definition, you should unindent it for it to be in the general scope of the file.

Also, `main` function is defined as a method of the class `GitCheckout`, it can only be called from an object of the class. you should unindent it and remove `self` from the parameters.

Also, self is passed implicitly, no need to pass it explicitly.

Try improving:

```
class GitCheckout:
    def parse_json(self, text):
        self.json_dict = json.loads(text)
        self.extract_data()

    def extract_data(self):
        des = self.json_dict["dest"]
        src = self.json_dict["src"]
        ver = self.json_dict["ver"]
        self.generate_git_cmd(str(des), str(src), str(ver))

    def generate_git_cmd(self, des, src, ver):
        if os.path.isdir(des):
            stdout = self.run_cmd(['rm', '-rf', des])
            print(stdout)
        else:
            self.run_cmd(['mkdir', '-p', des])
        stdout = self.run_cmd(['git', 'clone', '--no-checkout', src, des])

    def run_cmd(self, cmd):
        p = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True)
        p.stdout = p.stdout.decode("utf-8")
        return p.stdout

def main():
    obj = GitCheckout()
    args = sys.argv
    obj.parse_json(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is incorrect, your `main()` function isn't defined properly, and you aren't actually calling your `main()` function. Indentation should be like so (note the last two blocks are outdented):

```
class GitCheckout:
    def parse_json(self, text):
        self.json_dict = json.loads(text)
        self.extract_data()

    def extract_data(self):
        des = self.json_dict["dest"]
        src = self.json_dict["src"]
        ver = self.json_dict["ver"]
        self.generate_git_cmd(str(des), str(src), str(ver))

    def generate_git_cmd(self, des, src, ver):
        if os.path.isdir(des):
            stdout = self.run_cmd(['rm', '-rf', des])
            print(stdout)
        else:
            self.run_cmd(['mkdir', '-p', des])
        stdout = self.run_cmd(['git', 'clone', '--no-checkout', src, des])

    def run_cmd(self, cmd):
        p = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True)
        p.stdout = p.stdout.decode("utf-8")
        return p.stdout

def main():
    obj = GitCheckout()
    args = sys.argv
    obj.parse_json(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notice that I removed the `self` parameter from `main()`, as it isn't part of the class definition. I also added parentheses `()` to actually call `main()` in the last line.